# How to draw polygon from given coordinates

Tags: google-maps-api-3, polygon

I have coordinates saved in variables, and want to create a polygon from them.
I understand I need to use something like this:

```
var triangleCoords = [
new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262),
new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292),
new google.maps.LatLng(32.321384, -64.75737)
      ];

bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
   paths: triangleCoords,
  strokeColor: "#FF0000",
   strokeOpacity: 0.8,
  strokeWeight: 3,
  fillColor: "#FF0000",
  fillOpacity: 0.35
    });

    bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
```

My question is, how do I get my variables:

"point1" which contains something like "(22.944440598889003, 113.96972241210938)" into the paths for the polygon?

Comment: Are those "pointX" variables containing LatLng (aka Google maps coordinates) or are your numbers referring to coordinates under a different scale ?

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to add new vertex to polygon? Use array `.push()` method:

```
triangleCoords.push(new google.maps.LatLng(40, -70));
```

I used slightly different coordinates so that the polygon looks nice. You may want to redraw it:

```
bermudaTriangle.setMap(null); // remove the old triangle from map

// draw the new one:
bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
   paths: triangleCoords,
   strokeColor: "#FF0000",
   strokeOpacity: 0.8,
   strokeWeight: 3,
   fillColor: "#FF0000",
   fillOpacity: 0.35
});
bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe I was not very clear, what I need is to create a brand new polygon from scratch. I have the coordinates in variables (from my DB), how do I push them in?

Comment: @Marlon, if you think it answered the question, please accept the answer (click the tick - check mark - to the left of the answer).